# MATLAB Unable to Store Symbolic Function with Multiple Variables

Tags: matlab, syntax-error, symbolic-math

I'm trying to take the definite integral from -1 to 1 of a function with respect to `x`. The function has variables `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `x`, all of which I've defined as `syms` variables. I'm trying to keep `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` in my final integral because I'll later be differentiating with respect to each one for an optimization problem. Here's the current code that I have:

```
syms f(x);
syms a b c d;
f(x)= (exp(x)-a*(1/sqrt(2))-b*(sqrt(3/2)*x)-c((sqrt(45/8))*(x^2-(1/3)))+d((sqrt(175/8))*((x^3)-(3/5)*(x))))^2;
integral = int(f, x, [-1 1]);
disp(integral);
```

Similar code worked when I tried it using only variables `x` and `y` for a smaller function. However, when I try this code, I get:

> Error using sym/subsindex (line 825) Invalid indexing or function
>   definition. Indexing must follow MATLAB indexing. Function arguments
>   must be symbolic variables, and function body must be sym expression.
>
> Error in sym/subsref (line 870)
>               R_tilde = builtin('subsref',L_tilde,Idx);
>
> Error in HW11 (line 4)
>   f(x)= (exp(x)-a*(1/sqrt(2))-b*(sqrt(3/2)*x)-c((sqrt(45/8))*(x^2-(1/3)))+d((sqrt(175/8))*((x^3)-(3/5)*(x))))^2;

I'm pretty new to symbolic functions and `syms` variables in MATLAB, why is MATLAB rejecting this code? The similar code that I tried that worked was:

```
syms f(x);
syms y;
f(x) = (x^2) + y;
integral = int(f, x, [0 3]);
disp(integral);
```

Comment: Add the **_multiplication operator_** `*`right after `c` and `d` in `f(x)` expression, otherwise they will be interpreted as arrays

Comment: Thank you! This worked, I didn't even notice I was missing an operator there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59027013/matlab-unable-to-store-symbolic-function-with-multiple-variables#comment104304552_59027013) by [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11175375/adam), you probably forgot to add a multiplication operator `*` after the the `c` and `d`, so when you write `c(...)` and `d(...)` MATLAB treats these as indexing of an array but you cannot index arrays with symbolic variables or expressions. You need to change it to `c*(...)` and `d*(...)`.

Replace:

```
f(x)= (exp(x)-a*(1/sqrt(2))-b*(sqrt(3/2)*x)-c((sqrt(45/8))*(x^2-(1/3)))+d((sqrt(175/8))*((x^3)-(3/5)*(x))))^2;
```

With:

```
f(x)= (exp(x)-a*(1/sqrt(2))-b*(sqrt(3/2)*x)-c*((sqrt(45/8))*(x^2-(1/3)))+d*((sqrt(175/8))*((x^3)-(3/5)*(x))))^2;
```